# Option H not recognized by the compiler for figure placement

Tags: graphics, floats, positioning

I specify the H option in order to place exactly here a figure but the compiler doesn't recognize the option, here's my full code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-sc}
\usepackage[authoryear,longnamesfirst]{natbib}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{figure}[H]
 \centering
    \includegraphics{image.PNG}
\end{figure}
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

`cas-sc` (via `cas-common`) redefines floats so `float` package can not work. However `[H]`is almost never needed as its only purpose is to prevent floating which is the only reason to use `figure`. So you can just use `\includegraphics` (a) or if you need a caption you can use `\captionof` (b)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-sc}
\usepackage[authoryear,longnamesfirst]{natbib}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \includegraphics{example-image-a.png}
\end{center}


\noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
 \centering
 \includegraphics{example-image-b.png}
 \captionof{figure}{some caption text}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: how to ensure the "exactly here" placement of the figure for the case of cas-sc ?

Comment: @SSSOF that is exactly what  I show here.

Answer (score 0):

Its because you always have to add the `\begin{document}` ... `\end{document}` in latex. Otherwise, it will through error like the one you encountered

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-sc}
\usepackage[authoryear,longnamesfirst]{natbib}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
 \centering
    \includegraphics{image.PNG}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\begin{document} ... \end{document}` those are added, so it is not the problem

Comment: So what is your problem? Please explain.

Comment: my problem as explained is this red message :`The compiler isn't recognizing the float option 'H'. Include \usepackage{float} in your preamble to fix this`.

Comment: @SSSOF the answer by @afaq works correctly. Which LaTeX system do you have? Have you installed the package `float`? Do yo have more errors?

Comment: i don't have more problems, i am using overleaf

Comment: @SSSOF so, you should accept this answer ...

Comment: this answer is 0 to me. It goes without saying that document begin is included in the code. "I don't have more problems" refers to your prev comment instead.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I suspect the possible culprit is the cas-sc class. Try using the article class if you can. It compiles without any error or warnings also.

Comment: Did you test this answer? I get `! LaTeX Error: Unknown float option `H'.` If I use the code you suggest in this post.

Comment: I didn't compile it. Based on the MWE, the compler throws these kinds of error. I did point the cas-sc class, as mentioned in your solution